# ContextMenuStrip not showing nearby cursor

Tags: vb.net, winforms, contextmenu

I'm trying to create an event that shows a contextmenu when I right click a row in my datgridview.

Here is an image of the problem that is happening:

[image]

And here is the code I am currently using:

```
Private Sub dgvStudents_CellMouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgvStudents.CellMouseDown
    Dim rowClicked As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = dgvStudents.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
    'Select Right Clicked Row if its not the header row
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right AndAlso e.RowIndex > -1 Then
        'Clear any currently sellected rows
        dgvStudents.ClearSelection()
        Me.dgvStudents.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = True
        ContextMenuStrip1.Show(dgvStudents, Control.MousePosition)

    End If
End Sub
```

P.S the screen capture doesn't show my cursor >.> but it's definitely not synced with the context menu!

**EDIT**: Ok guys I've solved it,

I simply replaced Control.MousePosition to MousePosition and it worked!

Comment: The last time I used a context menu I didn't need to show it in the cellmousedown event. Have you tried just adding the context menu as a property of the datagridview?

Comment: Yeah I tried that mate, problem is It doesn't select the row with it and its shows when you click headers too >.>

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: I couldn't as not enough reputation :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mouse.Position is in screen coordinates.  You'll need to provide the relative coordinates, relative from dgvStudents.  They are handed to you on a silver platter through the event argument:

```
  ContextMenuStrip1.Show(dgvStudents, e.Location)
```

Context menus are normally displayed in response to mouse-up so do favor the CellMouseUp event instead.

Answer (score 6):

Neither of these worked for me.  The solution that got the menu to pop up under the mouse was:

```
ContextMenuStrip1.Show(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)
```